# IIS FTP Server User Isolation - Access denied with username having underscore '_' symbol

Tags: iis, ftp

I came across a very strange problem and thought maybe someone would help me. I followed a guide here: http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/how-to-set-up-ftp-access-for-multiple-users-with-user-isolation/ to setup IIS FTP Server with specific paths for each user using FTP User Isolation with usernames. All worked fine until I added a new user with an '_' underscore symbol in the username. For some reason the FTP connection is refused.

Is there anybody who experienced the same problem?

Comment: Is that account different from the others in any other way, and have you tried resetting the password?

Comment: Strangely enough the problem fixed itself after a server restart...